# Shipping msbuild task as nuget

Tags: c#, msbuild, nuget

I need your help.

I'm developing an msbuild task that performs certain actions upon msbuild.

I want my users to be able to download and install a nuget package and once the package is installed the build task will be part of the build process.

I know how to release a nuget package and i know how to includes a custom targets file together with the nuget, what i don't know is how to add the import statement to the csproj upon nuget installation:

Is there a way to do so or am i asking for too much?

Thanx!
Gilad

Answer (score 6):

The docs aren't in the easiest to find place, but [here's a link to the docs on including MSBuild props/targets files in your package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package#include-msbuild-props-and-targets-in-a-package).

Basically, you put the file in the package in the location `build\<tfm>\<package_id>.props`. For example `build\netstandard2.0\MyPackage.props`. If you want your build targets to be included in all TFMs, you can use `build\<package_id>.props`, but if your package also contains other assets like `lib/` or `contentFiles/`, the "no-TFM" build files will cause "asset-target fallback" to fail, so if your package has only `net472` libs, and the `build` files, a project targeting `netcoreapp3.0` will get only the `build` assets, none of the `net472` assets. If your `build` files are in a TFM folder, then NuGet's asset target fallback will select both the `lib` and `build` assets. So, I strongly encourage everyone to always use the TFM folder.

The docs need to be improved, but [the table explaining](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package#from-a-convention-based-working-directory)  lists `build`, `buildTransitive`, and `buildMultiTargeting`. Projects using `packages.config` only use build assets under `build`. Projects using `PackageReference` only use `build` and `buildMultiTargeting` assets when the project references the package directly. Assets under `buildTransitive` get selected when the package is pulled in transitively, rather than directly. The difference between `build` and `buildMultiTargeting` is complex. If you understand the concept of "inner-build" and "outer-build" in multi-targeting SDK style projects, that's the difference (`build` is inner-build), otherwise only use `build`.

I should update the docs to have this information.

Comment: There is documentation specifically for packaging msbuild tasks as NuGets: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/tutorial-custom-task-code-generation?view=vs-2022#package-the-task-for-distribution

Comment: And sample code: https://github.com/dotnet/samples/tree/main/msbuild/custom-task-code-generation